#  UITableView Grouped style in iPad

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using UITableView to show my app info but I don't why the tableview is not grouped style !! In the interface builder I change to the group style but does not change !!

![enter image description here][1]

Need to be like this :

[image]

EDITED :

```
- (IBAction)infoView {
    InfoViewController *showView = [[InfoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    showView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    showView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:showView animated:YES];
    [showView release]; 
}
```

INFOviewController is UITableView based subclass

```
@interface InfoViewController : UITableViewController
```

Comment: Can you show the code where this view controller is being created?

Comment: Try explicitly specifying the nib name instead of nil (even if it is the same as the class name).

Comment: @AppleVijay : Yes same issue !

Comment: @Anna : I mentioned the nib name but same problem

Comment: post ur no of section and other cellfor methods here

Comment: @ANNA YESSSS Your right ;) done :) I mentioned the wrong nib name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InfoViewController *showView = [[InfoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:InfoViewController bundle:nil];
```

Not specifying the Nib name leads to the changes made in Xib being ignored.